# How to run applescript until message is received

Tags: macos, applescript, imessage

I want to run an applescript script from the command line, and have a loop in it run until the a message is received. I'm updating a variable when a message is received using this:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from targetBuddy
        set gotMessage to true
    end message received
end using terms from
```

However, when I place this inside the `on run` block, I get an error at `on message received` saying "Expected “end” but found “on”." And when I place it outside the run block the script can be saved and will run, but the on message received handler isn't being called, which I checked by throwing a `log` statement in there. How can I get the script to check for a message being received while also running another loop?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run application event handlers outside the application because the event handler needs a target process with an AppleScript scripting definition (dictionary) to register the events and send the apple event to.

Comment: Okay. So if I want to end a script running in response to receiving a message, is there any way to do that?

Comment: you can specify a script in Messages.app > Preferences